# Create a folder inside existing subfolder in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Should be pretty easy right.. I am battling this. Or rather it battles me. So I do:

```
     net use w: /delete


     SET SERVER1=myserver
     SET ROOT_DRIVE=c$

     SET WEB_ROOT=\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\
     SET DESTINATION_FOLDER=PPA20_TEST


     net use w: \\%SERVER1%\%ROOT_DRIVE% /User:%usern% %password%  /persistent:yes 
     cd w:%WEB_ROOT%
     md %DESTINATION_FOLDER%
```

So supposedly this should create my DESTINATION_FOLDER inside WEB_ROOT folder under the mapped drive. Instead it creates it where that batch file is called from..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it doesn't change the active drive, it merely changes the active directory *on the drive `W:`*.

To change both the active drive and the active directory, use the `/D` switch:

```
cd /d w:%WEB_ROOT%
```

However, you may not really need to set the `w:%WEB_ROOT%` directory active. Just specify the full path in the `md` command:

```
md w:%WEB_ROOT%%DESTINATION_FOLDER%
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `w:` before your `cd w:%WEB_ROOT%` call, so it would be like this:

```
w:
cd w:%WEB_ROOT%
md %DESTINATION_FOLDER%
```

So you first change to drive `w:` to then change directory on it.